# A picturesque equivalent for German "Beutelschneiderei", i.e. what cut-purses and fraudsters do

Tags: idiom-requests

In German there is a term *Beutelschneiderei* which in all dictionaries I have currently access to is being translated as "daylight robbery". However, *Beutelschneiderei* in German is a very picturesque word (evoking mediaeval sceneries), and my impression is that "daylight robbery" is more of a sober description of the activity.

Here is the question: What better terms could I use in an English text to render German *Beutelschneiderei*.

I found

> cut-purse

as a term for the person involved in that business; cut-purse being an exact translation of *Beutelschneider*, which is the person; whereas *Beutelschneiderei* is the activity, or the trade, so perhaps something like

> cut-pursery (?).

Note that the term *Beutelschneiderei* does not only describe the occupation of a person concretely cutting with a knife or scissors people's purses off their belt. It can be used also **metaphorically** for any fraudulent activity aiming at taking money from people without returning a due service. For example "Trump University" could in German quite correctly be refered to as *Beutelschneiderei*. It is this metaphorical use that I am after, not so much the original physical activity of pursecutting.

Note also that *Beutelschneiderei* is not a legal term. In legal terms, a cut-purse would be prosecuted for theft (*Diebstahl*) or robbery (*Raub*), because these terms are defined by penal law.

I am sure there are nice words or idioms in English, given for example the rich 19th century literature describing life in the poorer parts of society.

---

**A concise version of this question** would be: What (ideally picturesque, possibly slightly ironic) expressions are there to describe fraud?

---

**Later found:**

Having had now access to one more dictionary, I can contribute to the list (that meanwhile has formed thanks to contributors):

> thievery

---

**And finally...**

... as forum members have posted quite a number of beautiful and interesting answers, and I see now that the semantic field is pretty broad, with all kinds of variables in it, here is the actual context where I want to use the expression: Speaking about various new forms of teaching and learning, I have here somebody claiming that "Providing a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) to learn leadership would simply be [your idiom for *Beutelschneiderei*]".

Comment: I can think of a few, but can you remove the single-word tag? English does not expand concepts into single words as neatly as German does.

Comment: 'Being mugged' springs to mind which not only refers to being physically robbed by violence but can also be related to underhand and devious methods of separating people from their hard earned.

Comment: @wetcircuit    Thanks for the hint. "Single word request" was indeed a misleading tag. I hope "idiom-request" fits better.

Comment: This is confusing, because *daylight robbery* (also *highway robbery*, if you want a more "picturesque" term) refers to **overcharging** - while what you're describing is a **fraudulent scheme**. These are two entirely different things.

Comment: @michael.hor257k    I do not claim that "daylight robbery" is a good translation. It is simply the only thing I so far found in dictionaries (even in two) for *Beutelschneiderei*. I am not happy with the translation, either. Therefore this question.

Comment: I'm approaching forty and this is the first time that I hear the word *Beutelschneiderei*. Picturesque indeed. So much so, I don't think anyone here would actually understand it. A proper English translation would need to be just as impenetrable.

Comment: @RegDwigнt   I happily welcome impenetrable translations. But if you you know where the word comes from, namely from mediaeval times when people carried their coins around in small leather bags attached by a string to their belt, and thieves would just try to cut these strings to catch the purse - it does not seem so impenetrable anymore, or does it?

Comment: [dict.leo of Beutelschneider](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/beutelschneider) gives  'swindle' (a perfectly good english word). So 'a swindle' (the theft or fraud) or 'the swindler' (the person doing it) might work for you.  'Cut-purse' is pretty good metaphorically, but 'cut-pursery' just sounds wrong for the act.

Comment: In the famous book, Cotton Comes to Harlem, the thief does actually cut away the back of a lady's dress and cuts the strings off the purse she has hanging there. It is soooo funny.

Comment: @Mitch  I used Leo for checking what they have on *Beutelschneiderei* (so the derived noun, not the job title), and so far there was only the aforementioned *daylight robbery*.

Comment: In your example usage, the idiom in UK would be "daylight robbery"

Comment: Daylight Robbery is not  about robbery committed in day light in English is more used in this way "what £7.50 for a pint of Guinness that's daylight robbery "

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann dict.leo is great (inside a few links there is a Q&A board that a lot of good translators ask and answer questions). But like any reference, it is not perfect. But then there may be no good exact translation worthy of having an entry there (ELU suffers from questions assuming that there must be an exact answer). Or 'daylight robbery' may well be exactly the right thing. I don't know.

Comment: This question has got confused and changed a great deal over the course of its edits. Those who have contributed answers have been essentially answering different questions and wasting their time as a result. FWIW _a scam_ or _a swindle_ complete the .example sentence well.

Comment: Yes, daylight robbery has become far more metaphorical over the years, the idiomatic use for blatant overcharging comes out of the old idea that most theft type crimes used to happen in the dark for lack of witnesses and stealth, so only the most skilled and bold thieves would dare commit a crime in full daylight, where they had a much greater chance of both being apprehended in the act, and observed by witnesses, and apprehended later. The metaphor takes the "blatant and bold" part and applies it to charges for goods and services.

Comment: IMO, the word for your last example with MOOC is _scam_

Answer (score 32):

A well-known idiom is **Highway Robbery**.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highway%20robbery

[image]

**It refers to 18th Century "highwaymen" who robbed travelers on a public but unprotected road in broad daylight.** Highwaymen are romanticized for being "bold" and eluding capture, and are typically depicted as being gentry or noble class with refined manners, above the "common" criminal because they own expensive items like a horse and a pistol.

**The idiom is used for unfair business practices, especially price gouging**, and implies the situation is somehow immune to corrective market forces, protected from competition, or taking advantage of a legal loophole.

Comment: Can you perhaps include the definition of "Highway Robbery" in your answer? While a picture is worth a thousand words, I can't tell which of those are the definition :)

Comment: @scohe001 editing...

Comment: Very well explained, thank you! The context (about your US version of Robin Hood, so to say) is important.

Comment: This has two points to recommend it over other answers: the aspect of *brazen* theft and the fact that it's a common phrase for the purpose. A variant is *daylight robbery*

Comment: Stand and deliver! Your money or your life!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think "Robin Hood" is overstating it a bit. I've never heard somebody use "highway robbery" in a positive connotation, its just that it really emphasises the sheer brazen-ness of the act.

Answer (score 14):

How about [skullduggery](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/skullduggery)?

(It doesn't seem to be related to 'skull', so in that sense it's not really visual, more onomatopoeic)

> dishonorable proceedings; mean dishonesty or trickery: bribery, graft,
>   and other such skulduggery.
>   n.1856, apparently an alteration of Scottish sculdudrie "adultery"
>   (1713), sculduddery "bawdry, obscenity" (1821), a euphemism of
>   uncertain origin.

[Hocus pocus](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hocus-pocus?s=t) might also do the trick.

> 3.trickery; deception.

Comment: So far, and based on the definition given in the box, *skullduggery* seems like a really good word for me, indeed!

Comment: 'skullduggery' is accurate as primary definition, but it has old-fashioned connotations and sounds quaint.

Comment: Skulduggery, at least as I've heard it used, doesn't evoke theft as I believe cut-purse does.

Comment: It's a great word but it not necessarily robbery at all.

Comment: Nope. At this point it doesn't resemble the original German word at all.

Comment: Great word. In its defence, robbery's not necessarily part of the answer OP wants. (The question could be much clearer.)

Answer (score 7):

[image]**"purse-snatching"** is the kind of robbery where a purse, handbag or small package is grabbed from another person.

> The [National Incident-Based Reporting System](https://definedterm.com/a/definition/70654) defines purse-snatching as "the grabbing or snatching of a purse, handbag, etc., from the physical possession of another person."

EDIT - The OP edited and added "I have here somebody claiming that "Providing a MOOC to learn leadership would simply be __________________".

In this case you're looking for a word or phrase that can be used metaphorically for "a crooked deal". I then suggest what was mentioned by the OP "daylight robbery".

Comment: Which related to the actual snatching of actual purses. Good to have that word. But would it be applicable also metaphorically to more general fraud?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I don't recall ever hearing purse-snatching in English to mean anything but taking of personal property held on someone's person - I would not suggest it for more general fraud.

Comment: Why is that woman yelling at a man skateboarding while carrying an Erlenmeyer flask?

Answer (score 5):

Since you did bring it up and made changes to your original question, I must include "**trumpery**" which can be used as a noun to express fraud.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trumpery

http://libertyworks.com/insipid-trumpery-1/

> Are you engaging in **trumpery**, Sir?

I am not sure about its dubious "**picturesque**" qualities (**see second link**), but perhaps this lesser/obscure definition will gain future acceptance.

Comment: It's *trumpery*, not *Trumpery*.

Comment: How did I not see that? Thanks.

Comment: Haha! Well answered, Sir! Trumpery may have been not so picturesque initially, but recently it seems to have gained picturesqueness, I do not know exactly why. I am considering to use this for my purpose (it might be a bit strong, but... well... why not; for the sake of being contemporianious...)

Comment: Ah. If you only knew. Always good to be of help.

Comment: There is a word trumpery? No way!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Way!!!! See [this from Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trumpery). I make no further commemt for fear of giving offence.

Comment: Internet commentary and almost all social media is a cesspool of offense, SE is not that.  But, consider this, I actually did offend someone at a garden center this summer because I said sometimes I preferred to buy foreign made products  - shhhhh - I need to keep "that one" under my hat.  It's all about national pride. How quickly we forget. It certainly is thought provoking though.

Answer (score 4):

As you are looking for a picturesque / metaphorical expression, idiomatic if possible, I immediately thought of the handywork of a Quacksalber. Someone who is selling / promising a fraudulent product.

> Providing a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) to learn leadership
>   would simply be [snake oil](https://www.dict.cc/?s=snake%20oil) [peddlery](https://www.dict.cc/?s=peddlery)

Or even simpler

> Providing a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) to learn leadership
>   would simply be [snake oil](https://www.dict.cc/?s=snake%20oil)

Or

> Providing a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course) to learn leadership
>   would simply be [quackery](https://www.dict.cc/?s=quackery)

Other terms that are related might also fit well here:
see [Schwindel](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Schwindel.html)
and find gems like:
mare's nest, rip-off, hanky-panky, swizz, goldbrick, sham, shenanigans, swindle, bogusness, skullduggery, quackery, fiddle, diddle, flam, humbug, boodle, hokum

Comment: Snake oil is a great word (and so very picturesque!) but probably fits best for a  fraudulently ineffective *remedy.* As an example, the German blogger Felix von Leitner uses it for anti virus programs (which open more attack paths than they close, in his opinion). For a MOOC it doesn't seem to fit so well. For a therapy course, by contrast, it would.

Answer (score 3):

That would be the colorful idiom "**pickpocket**". It is picturesque, similar in meaning, and can be used as both a noun and a verb.

> Is she a pack rat or a **pickpocket**?
>
> He **pickpocketed** those a long time ago.

and also:

> **Pickpocketing**, as an activity, is the subject of my book.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pickpocket

Comment: But is there a similary nice **noun for the activity** (rather than the person)? Pick-pocketry? Pick-pocketing? And is pick pocket not rather used for concrete theft of purses and other valuables, and not so much in a **metaphorical** way (as for Trump University or whatever other fraudulent endeavour)?

Comment: The most common word for the activity would be "pickpocketing" It sounds like a cheerful activity. It could even be offered as a vocational course.

Comment: Cheerful is good. *Beutelschneiderei* similarly has a touch of being a nice, pleasant, eco-friendly, sociable activity (as long as the original physical activity is meant; the cheerfulness does not apply to the broader sense of fraud).

Comment: pickpocketing and petty thievery: https://books.google.com/books?id=Z4SL2X3uHEAC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=%22petty+thievery%22++%2B+middle+ages&source=bl&ots=klm_HF6xHE&sig=JtdNtgbMQI9kilU39RK-kGloOiE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8pYO1z-rdAhXtRd8KHUUNDSIQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22petty%20thievery%22&f=false

Comment: The Victorians had the phrase _finger smith_ for a pick pocket. So the crime would be _finger smithery_

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want the activity to sound *picturesque* and that you seem to be open to words relating to *fraud* in general, rather than just *pickpocketing:*

---

> [**heist**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heist)
>
> *(verb)* **to commit armed robbery; steal**
>
> *(noun)*  **armed robbery; holdup; *also* theft**

Dictionaries differ on exactly what a *heist* constitutes. In American English (and perhaps elsewhere), it can be a straight theft or robbery (as in the Merriam-Webster definition above) but it often suggests a planned criminal enterprise. Macmillan gives the following definition:

> [**heist**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/heist#heist_4)
>
> **an organized attempt by thieves to steal something**

[Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heist) describes a *heist* as:

> ...**a grand, high-end theft from an institution such as a bank or a museum, or any theft in which there is a large haul of loot**.

If you type in ["Hatton Garden"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatton_Garden_safe_deposit_burglary), Google suggests "heist", at least at the time of writing.

*Heist* is surprisingly non-judgemental as a word, and could be perhaps used in the lighthearted way you seem to want. Indeed, the word *heist*  is [often used in movie titles](https://www.imdb.com/find?q=heist&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr) and is often (but not exclusively) used to romanticise crime.

I've also included the entry from Oxford Living Dictionaries, mainly for the example sentences, rather than the definition, which isn't great:

> [**heist**](//en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/heist) *(noun, informal)*
>
> **a robbery**
>
> *a diamond heist*
>
> *The panel suggested a radical re-think of sentencing for all types of robbery, ranging from street muggings to professionally-organised
>   heists.*
>
> *Sure, the men behind the robbery looked pretty clever in the immediate aftermath of the heist.*
>
> *The work is filled with mentions of murders, drug heists and beatings, but the focus ultimately - and affectingly - rests on the
>   more quotidian dramas.*
>
> *So, despite this week's raid, heists will always be rare, with most real criminals dealing in the nastier side of law-breaking: petty
>   theft, often involving violence, and drugs.*
>
> *Collectively the three escapees faced three charges of murder, 16 counts of attempted murder and seven armed robbery charges relating to
>   cash-in-transit heists across the province.*

---

More light-hearted again is *caper*. To give a full sense of how jovial a word it is, it's worth looking at the full definition:

> [**caper**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/caper)
>
> *(verb, no object, with adverbial of direction)*
>
> **skip or dance about in a lively or playful way**
>
> *Children were capering about the room.*
>
> *(noun)*
>
> 1 **a playful skipping movement**
>
> *She did a little caper or dance.*
>
> 2 
>   *(informal)* **an illicit or ridiculous activity or escapade**
>
> *I'm too old for this kind of caper.*
>
> 2.1 **a light-hearted, far-fetched film, especially about crime**
>
> *a cop caper about intergalactic drug dealers*

It's the second sense we intend here, of course, and you can see the flavour of the word is decidedly upbeat, and that *caper* is more general a term than *heist.*

Further example sentences for the second sense from the same dictionary follow:

> *Unfortunately, far too many films contain wacky crime capers that lead into shenanigans which gives way to witty, edgy banter.*
>
> *Women wrestled then befriended adultresses, men abducted brides, light-hearted capers segued into murder.*
>
> *The election board and the local Council, with their haphazard and
>   non-accountability attitude, should have stopped this caper when it
>    was first seen years ago.*
>
> *Now he may face the full 10 years, plus punishment for the grave-robbing caper.*
>
> *A guy comes up with a caper, he puts together a team, they plan, and
>    then they pull off the heist.*

Pickled flower buds aside, Macmillan gives the following definition:

> [**caper**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/caper_1#caper_5)
>   *(informal)*
>
> **an activity that is not honest or not very serious**

[The Pink Panther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pink_Panther) involves a *heist* but it is also definitely a *caper,* in several senses of the word.

---

*Shenanigans,* the name of countless faux Irish bars the world over, featured in one of the example sentences earlier, but is also worth consideration in its own right:

> [**shenanigans**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shenanigans)
>
> **silly, dishonest, or immoral behaviour**

*Shenanigans* again, is a very light-hearted and general term for the kind of *antics* a *rogue* or a *rascal* might get up to. You might *be up to* or *engage in shenanigans.*

Comment: Thank you for this exhaustive answer with various good expressions. Heist would be, I suppose, something that is openly wrongdoning. If so, it would not fit well into where I need it (for something hiddenly wrong), but still it is good to have a broader field of notions available here.

Comment: Also, all related to cons (a subset of fraud, I suppose), _sting, scam, bunco, flimflam, swindle, grift_  and _hustle_ are also all worth consideration. Perhaps because of the way that confidence tricksters are often romanticised on TV and in film, these words can convey a certain cheeky or roguish charm. You may look them up yourself, if you're interested!

Comment: A _heist_ isn't necessarily out in the open. Nor indeed is a _caper!_ _Shenanigans_ is quite like _skulduggery_ in its general import, but far less sinister.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it used much in the current times but (and perhaps therefore) ***chicanery*** may fit the bill too.

> Speaking about various new forms of teaching and learning, I have here
>   somebody claiming that "Providing a MOOC (Massive Open Online Course)
>   to learn leadership would simply be ***chicanery***".

ODO:

> **[chicanery](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chicanery)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> The use of deception or subterfuge to achieve one's purpose.
>
> ‘His sky-rocket ascent was almost certainly powered by bribery,
>   manipulation, and other chicanery.’

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some great answers, but I would like to add the particularly evocative of an image **[lifted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lifted)**:

> 4a : STEAL
>
> had her purse lifted
>
> b : PLAGIARIZE
>
> c : to take out of normal setting

It evokes the image of picking something up and taking it away, though with "lifted" there is almost always a victim or a place required to use it. "I lifted this item from the store," "he lifted the phone from Sally," or "that idea was completely lifted from McDonald's!"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "hoodwink," "bamboozle," or "swindle."  If it's a noun you're looking for, "hucksterism" is also a possibility.